# Intuition behind group theory problem

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I'm looking at the following problem (3.1:1 in invitation to general algebra and universal constructions by Bergman), and hoping for some more intuition/explanation.

> Suppose $F$  and $G$ are groups, and $a,b,c\in F$ and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in G$, and consider the following statements.
>
> a) every group theoretic equation $p=q$ satisfied by $(a,b,c)$ in $F$ is also satisfied by $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \in G$
>
> b) There exists a homomorphism $h:F\to G$ under which $h(a)=\alpha$, $h(b)=\beta$, $h(c)= \gamma$.
>
> Show by example it is possible for a) to hold but b) to fail.

I stumbled on the following counterexample. Take the tuples $(0,2)\in \mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $(0,1)\in\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. The subgroup $\langle 0,2\rangle\subsetneq \mathbb{Z}_4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so evidently any equation in the former holds in the latter. But no hom $h:\mathbb{Z}_4\to\mathbb{Z}_2$ with $h(0)=0$ and $h(2)=1$ can exist, since if $h(1)=x$ say, we have $x+x=h(1)+h(1)=h(1+1)=h(2)=1$, which has no solutions for $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Apart from finding this example, I have no intuition for why this is happening. Could someone provide some explanation? All that I can see is that while condition a) guarantees us a hom from the generated subgroup $\langle a,b,c\rangle\to G$, it is not always possible to extend this to a hom out of the full group $F\to G$

Comment: Didn't you already answer your own question? A homomorphism may not remain a homomorphism when the domain is extended.

Comment: maybe I did and there's nothing deeper. What about some alternate counterexamples?

Comment: What's the role in the counterexample of two $2$-tuples you have taken?

Comment: @MerkZockerborg A homomorphism $\mathbb Z \to G$ is just a choice of the image of $1$ while for any finite group $G$ there exists only the trivial homomorphism $\mathbb Q \to G$. Choose your favorite non-trivial finite group $G$ and non-identity element in $G$ as the image of $1$ to get an example.

Comment: I don't see how your counterxample fits with the statements: shouldn't be $F=\langle 0,2\rangle$ rather than $\Bbb Z_4$?

Comment: It's not a "counterexample", it's, as the statement of tge problem says, an example.

Comment: It's how the OP named it, it's a matter  of communication. Nonetheless, it doesn't comply with the ststements.

Comment: Since homomorphisms satisfy $\phi(x^n) = \phi(x)^n$, any polynomial identity satisfied in $\langle x_1, \ldots, x_n\rangle$ will be satisfied in $\langle \phi(x_1), \ldots, \phi(x_n) \rangle$ so (b) implies (a). While I'm not sure what is meant by "every group theoretic equation", one would imagine this includes everything generating the multiplication table for $\langle a,b,c \rangle$, so as you noted there should exist an isomorphism $\langle \alpha, \beta, \gamma \rangle$...

Comment: ...Thus (a) implies (b) as long as the group is generated by these three elements, but this is clearly not sufficient in general; consider basically any group which isn't finitely generated. The point of my prior comment was that $\mathbb Q$ isn't finitely generated, so we can use it as model. If you want to conform exactly to three generators, I believe you could just consider $\mathbb Q^3$ with $\mathbb Z^3$ as a subgroup (so the three elements are the generators of each $\mathbb Z$ and are thus independent, so there isn't any nontrivial relation between them)

Comment: thanks @BrevanEllefsen 

"every group theoretic equation" basically refers to any equation $p=q$ where $p$ and $q$ are "group theoretic terms in 3 symbols", i.e. finite expressions formed of $\cdot$, $^{-1}$, the group identity, parentheses, and three variables.

Also, probably a rookie question, but what's the easiest way to see that there are no nontrivial homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Q}$ to a finite group?

Comment: @Devo bad use of language on my part, but the point is it's a counterexample to the claim that "a) => b)".

I wrote it a bit fast and loose, but the example works because, say, $(0,0,2)$ is a tuple of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_4$, and $(0,0,1)$ is a tuple of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, such that any "equation" satisfied by the former tuple in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ will also be satisfied by the latter tuple in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (i.e. condition a), however there is no hom $\mathbb{Z}_4\to\mathbb{Z}_2$ that maps 0 to 0 and 2 to 1 (condition b fails)

Comment: I guess some ambiguity is caused here since I'm really only using two distinct elements $a,b\in F$ and $\alpha,\beta\in G$ rather than three

Answer (score -1):

Some comments:

1. Given that the problem asks for an "example", I would say that calling it a "counterexample" is a little confusing. Generally, we speak about a counterexample as an example the shows that a particular statement is false. Had the question been "Does (a) imply (b)?" then you might talk about a counterexample to the implication. But if the problem says "Given a example showing that (a) may hold even if (b) does not", then on first reading I would expect a "counterexample" to be something showing that what Bergman wrote is somehow false, or that a question has a negative answer, which is not the case.
2. You are being asked for an example satisfying certain properties. Specifically, you should name two groups, and three elements in each group, and show that (a) holds for those two groups and two triples of elements, but that (b) does not. You did not actually do that. Instead, you should specify that triples of elements you are choosing. You also confuse matters by talking about "tuple[] $(0,2)\in\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$" when the question asks about ordered triples of elements of the group. While technically $(0,2)$ is a "tuple", we are not thinking of it as a tuple here, but rather as simply an element of the group.

That said, your example can be whipped into proper form. We take $F=\mathbb{Z}_4\times Z_2$ and $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$ (not $\mathbb{Z}_4$ as you do...). Then we take elements $a=b=(0,0)\in F$ and $c=(2,0)\in F$, and corresponding elements $\alpha=\beta=0\in G$, $\gamma=1\in G$. Then you argue that (a) holds for $(a,b,c)$ and $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ because there is an isomorphism $\phi\colon\langle a,b,c\rangle \to \langle \alpha,\beta,\gamma\rangle$ sending $a$ to $\alpha$, $b$ to $\beta$, and $c$ to $\gamma$, so any identity $p=q$ that is satisfied by $(a,b,c)$ will necessarily be satisfied by $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$. That is correct. Then you argue that (b) fails to hold because there is no group homomorphism $f\colon F\to G$ that sends $c$ to $\gamma$, which is also correct.

There are a couple of points to this problem. This problem is in the section that motivates the construction of free groups (in three different ways, in sections 3.2, 3.3, and 3.4). The free group is characterized by the fact that you can specify an identification of (certain) elements with elements of a different group, and that will *necessarily* yield a homomorphism.

But more importantly, this problem follows Lemma 3.1.1, which reads:

> **Lemma 3.1.1.** Suppose that $F$ and $G$ are groups, such that $F$ is generated by three elements $a,b,c\in F$, while $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are any three elements of $G$. Then the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (a) Every group theoretic relation $p=q$ satisfied by $(a,b,c)$ in $F$ is also satisfied by $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ in $G$.
>
> (b) There exists a group homomorphism $h\colon F\to G$ under which $a\mapsto \alpha$, $b\mapsto\beta$, $c\mapsto\gamma$.
>
> Further, when these conditions hold, the homomorphism $h$ of (b) is unique.
>
> If the assumption that $a$, $b$, and $c$ generate $F$ is dropped, one still has (b)$\implies$(a).

So, what is the point of the problem? The point of the problem is to show that this statement is best possible. That if you drop the assumption that $a$, $b$, and $c$ generate, you no longer have that (a) implies (b), even though this assumption is not needed for the implication that (b) implies (a). What you "see", in the final paragraph, is precisely the reason this does not work. That was the other point.